# Are there other countries that embed politics in every subject like China?

Tags: china

I learned a very interesting phrase in China: [课程思政](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%BE%E7%A8%8B%E6%80%9D%E6%94%BF/22421661)(Ideological and Political Theories teaching in All Courses, starting from 2014, an idea of Shanghai municipal government) where every knowledge point in every subject should relate to politics.

For instance, this chapter about DNA in biology:

[image]

It says that communism's DNA is to serve the people and govern the country forever.

I wonder if only China applies this method? Or there are some other countries doing it also?

Comment: What is the source?  It seems to be part of training material for teachers, rather than a text book for students.

Comment: Relevant guidance for *English* schools https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/380595/SMSC_Guidance_Maintained_Schools.pdf

Comment: @JamesK Good to know that, and I will read it.

Comment: Kinda of a vague question ultimately. Generally most totalitarian regimes changed the curriculum in one way or another to fit their views, see e.g. "Nazi science" https://www.ushmm.org/collections/bibliography/nazi-racial-science ; https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/beyond-the-racial-state/eugenics-racial-science-and-nazi-biopolitics/8236AD6B8961BAB68AEC4704EB85408F https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.1414822112 Your title Q gets to discussion what "every" means, etc.

Comment: And likewise for "combine'. It's a spectrum from inserting ass-kissing analogies that don't seem to affect the science itself being taught, as in your example, to forbidding or demanding the teaching of one thing or the other e.g. not teaching evolution, or teaching that creationism is equally valid etc. (to pick some US examples).

Comment: @Fizz Maybe imbed is better?

Comment: Communism's DNA? Not a very biological book then.

Comment: Does this question relate only to countries still existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teachers in Germany are [supposed](https://bildungsserver.berlin-brandenburg.de/fileadmin/bbb/rlp-online/Teil_B/2020_12_15_OHR_Demokratiebildung.pdf) to represent democratic values in all subjects they teach (a "Querschnittsaufgabe" or "cross-sectional task"). That doesn't mean holding a democratic vote about having an exam that week. It does mean to value every student, standing up for human and civil rights, for justice, and things like that. If they do it well, it won't be blatantly obvious, but it is no less real for that. And **not** representing democracy would mean representing not-democracy, so they cannot avoid taking a stand. The law, ultimately the constitution, sets out what that stand has to be for a civil servant.

It comes down to the nature of [curriculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum) development. It is never possible to teach isolated facts without also reinforcing a culture. Those who claim that what they do is not political are deceiving themselves, or their audience.

Say you have a [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) class. Are the students *just* learning a branch of mathematics, or are they learning more than that? Well, if they would be deducted points on an exam for an answer to a [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics_education)) for grammar and spelling errors, then it isn't just mathematics. So it would be fair to say that any mathematics class *also* becomes education whatever language it is held in. And in other subjects. Presentation skills, for instance. In primary school, mathematics/arithmetic shades into motor skills, jointly with writing, and also, *always*, into social skills of learning in class. Listening, concentration, and all that.

Comment: I don't know. I went to school in Germany and except maybe for history lessons where for obvious reasons Nazis were the worst, the remaining teachings were remarkably unideological. Math really was only math. I don't have China as a comparison but I can imagine there might be big differences.

Comment: Not my DV and I kinda agree with the idea that it's a continuum, but on the other hand multi-party democracies generally disallow open party advertisements in schools. On the other hand, many communist countries had the portrait of the leader in every school  classroom, so there's that [political] personality cult obvious even in schools... although if one seeks similarities to that, religious symbols (i.e. cross) in the classroom had a somewhat similar role in other countries before state-church separation, and sometimes even after.

Comment: @Trilarion, a cynic might say that *the indoctrination was so successful you did not even notice.* Mainstream German society likes to think that their consensus view (soziale Marktwirtschaft, nivellierte Mittelschichtsgesellschaft, Rechtstaat) are so obviously *right* that alternatives don't have to be discussed at length. But they guide how teachers teach all subjects.

Comment: @Fizz, you are right regarding party politics. But what about the things most parties agree? They are only worth debating if one takes the alternative seriously.

Comment: @o.m. There still might be big differences. I have never experienced Chinese education, so I don't know, but it seems you haven't either. As I said, math was really only math and nothing of the consensus view (soziale Marktwirtschaft, nivellierte Mittelschichtsgesellschaft, Rechtstaat) as far as I remember. Now maybe also in China math is only math. We would need somebody who is experienced in both systems in order to meaningfully compare and rate them on their ideological content.

Comment: @Trilarion, I presume your school time was some years ago. Take one of your old maths textbooks, and a modern one, and look at the pictures. How many male and female engineers back then, how many today? How many male and female shoppers back then, how many today? That's **politics as a cross-sectional task,** not just a whim of the writers.

Comment: @o.m. Not sure that there were any people at all in my math books. But still, who knows how big the difference with China is. I don't say that there is this effect, I just say that the amplitude is completely unknown and could be vastly different. We really would need a comparative study, somebody who really opens up these books and compares them.

Comment: I could still have some of these books (although not all because I rented most of them), so I could have a critical look some time.

Comment: @Trilarion, if there were no people, just numbers, you're even older than I am. Textbooks, especially at primary and middle school, use lots of pictures to engage the student. In the 70s they reflected 70s society and values, in the 80s they reflected 80s society and values, and so on. Just one decade later, they can feel dissonant. An English book where kids debate if they should spend money on a new skateboard or a new mp3 player, for instance. Who has one of those, any more? But gender roles (or the deliberate lack of gender roles) also changed over time. That's intentional.

Comment: -1: I feel like if you're teaching trigonometry and your exam has an essay question on it, you're teaching trigonometry wrong.  If you're deducting points for spelling/grammar errors in a math class (unless the answer is completely indecipherable and you actually can't understand if the answer is correct or not, which is a whole other problem if this is a high-school level course), you're also teaching trigonometry wrong.  It's very easy to teach facts without political influence, just don't put political influence into your class.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason why math (and, as much as possible, any STEM discipline) classes don't (or shouldn't) have essay questions on their exams is precisely for this reason, because you want to explicitly exclude language communication from the discussion of whether or not the student understands the core concepts of the class.  If you're not teaching this way, you may be a bad teacher.

Comment: @Ertai87, it is a question of definitions. I believe that being able to communicate scientific results is a key goal of science education. (For instance, are 1,000 miles best represented as 1,609 km, 1,600 km, or 2,000 km? Depends on what you want to say.)

Comment: In maths you generally avoid marking for spelling/grammar explicitly, but language comprehension affects reading the questions and instructions.

Comment: @benjimin, who is that "you"? Are you teaching or talking from your school experience? Where? I recall being expected to do proper sentences ... Lower Saxony in the 1980s.